# Node JS get text value not working quite right

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

When attempting to access the text content of an ID, I have tried 2 different ways -

```
var username = requests.query.username;
var username = $('#username').text();
```

The first attempt returned undefined, and the second attempt returned an empty string. Of course when I try and push this to my SQL server, it returns an error because it is a null value.

I thought about using JSDOM to insert the table into the html code and referencing the table values in the javascript, but I could not find any resources to do so.

Additionally, let it be known I am using NodeJS and that my HTML pages are separate from the JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code posted from your node app or frontend JS?

Looking at the code its a bit unclear because you are using

```
requests.query.username;
```

then

```
$('#username').text();
```

Now assuming this was on the front end, the first variable of

```
requests.query.username;
```

Would have to be looking for a key of a nested object that would look like

```
request = {query:{username:"usersname"}}
```

And the other code block

```
$('#username').text();
```

Would appear to be using jQuery and trying to get the 'text' of the div with ID of username.

So without more context its hard to say but, assuming this is on the nodejs side, then jquery will not work, there is no DOM for the selectors to work off of so that would never work (there are packages that can try and make this work but by default it wont, nor should you really need to do that)

Now on the inverse, if you are doing this on the client, then, depending on the type of data you are trying to get [text, input value, innnerHTML] would dictate how what jquery call you make $("#username").text(), .html(), .val().

With more context as to what you are doing would probably get you a better answer

Comment: This code is on the nodejs side of it, which is server-side, but it needs to be evaluated when the user clicks on a button - client-side.
I thought about using localstorage to try and store the values and then extract them on the nodejs side of things. Although I am new to nodejs

Comment: So are you posting the data to your backend application and passing the userID? If that is the case then the 'username' would be part of the request object, so typically it would be like req.body.username <-- username would be passed via the form or data object. On the client side you could use localstorage OR pass that as part of a hidden input on the client side, really depends on how you have it setup.

Comment: My form looks like 
<form action="/createUser" method="POST">
 <fieldset>
 <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
</fieldset>
</form>

and then in the JS code
app.post('/createUser', function(request, response){
var username=  request.body.username
}

it returns undefined.

Comment: @ZacharyPavelski Your going to need to provide more code here buddy.. The post action should contain all form elements in the request.body, so on your route, do a console.log(req.body) (req is the request object on the route, so the variable name may be different then req, use what ever you have defined it as in the route) Once you console the request body you should be able to see the value and access it like req.body.username or what ever the value was. Form elements need to have  'name' attribute, that will be passed in the reuqest body

Comment: That was absolutely what I needed, you're amazing. Thank you for the guidance!!!!!!